How do I prevent linux from changing the frequency of my AMD zen4 processor? I want to benchmark. I am on amazon aws Ubuntu 24
buntu@ip-:/proc$ cat cpuinfo | grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2766.620
cpu MHz     : 3049.748
cpu MHz     : 3149.809
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
ubuntu@ip-:/proc$ cat cpuinfo | grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2793.340
cpu MHz     : 3102.449
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cpu MHz     : 2845.526

ubuntu@ip-:/proc$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no


AMD EPYC 9R14


The CPU is designed to lower its clock rate when it does not have to do a lot of computation. Linux is not responsible for that.
The frequency shown in the output of that command is the instantaneous frequency, which depends on how much of the cpu is utilized.
However, if you run a benchmark or a program that requires a lot of processing power, it should run at the full power of the processor.
If you want to see the maximum frequency, run the command lscpu | grep "CPU max MHz".
Alternatively, you can use the cpufetch tool with sudo apt install cpufetch.

Linux both, for intel and AMD, is supposed to have a frequency governor which can be tuned with cpupower by people wanting to run benchmarks and for other reasons. You can read more here: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html
